# The General Validity of $ab=cd$ Implies $ba=dc$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am doing some research of my own and I have a brief question and I don't recall studying this particular thing.  Is it generally true that if a set coupled with a binary operation is closed under inverses and has an identity then $ab=cd$ implies $ba=dc$ for all $a,b,c,d$ in the set?  If not, would this statement hold true for groups?

Comment: Is the binary operation associative ?

Comment: Not necessarily. That's why I make the distinction later by mentioning groups.

Comment: Consider for example $GL(2,\mathbb R)$, with $A$ identitiy matrix. If $B=CD$, then, in general, it is not true that $B=DC$ as it implies that $C$ and $D$ commute.

Comment: @Avitus You should make this an answer.  I really like this response.

Comment: @Jebruho ok, but I have some troubles in writing matrices...I need to search for the LaTeX commands :-) Sorry about that

Comment: @Jebruho  Notation improved. Nice question, btw.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As long as your operation has an identity, the property

$$ab = cd \Rightarrow ba=dc$$

is equivalent to commutativity: if the operation is commutative, the implication is obvious, for the other direction, put $c=1$ and $d=ab$ to get $ab = ba$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $GL(2,\mathbb R)$. It is a non empty set with binary associative composition, unit and inverses.

Let $A$ be the unit matrix, $B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, $C=\
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\
\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $AB=B=CD$; but $B=DC$ is not true.

Answer (score 5):

Counterexample: Consider the group $S_3$.
$$(13)(12)=(123)e$$
However:
$$(12)(13)\not=e(123)$$

Answer (score 3):

Another one may be arisen in $Q_8$, the quaternion group. Just take $a=x,y=b=c,d=x^{-1}$.

Comment: $+ \quad \overset{\bigcap}{\overline{\ddot\smile}}$